# Using MailKit to connect to a mail server from a third-party hosting provider

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mailkit

If I am hosting an asp.net core app through a third-party hosting provider such as [A2 Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/) is it possible to use this to send mail w/ Mail Kit? I have tried so many different things and client.Connect just hangs and eventually throws an exception. Ex is null.

**Here is my code:**

```
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                client.Connect("mail.mydomain.com", 25, false);

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("contact@mydomain.com", "PASSWORD");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my ISP (Comcast) blocks port 25. My hosting company told me they open up port 2525 for this reason. I changed it to 2525 and it worked. Contact your hosting company if you run into a similar issue and see what additional ports they might have opened up.